# 0014 W3602 : Error 0 on line 19, column 1: : will trying to get value from table

Tags: vbscript

I tried to run a script to get value from a table. First check if record exists if yes then extract the customer name. Below is the script I use.

Script Use:

```
'Get Customer Name from Customer List based on Customer Number extracted

CustomerNumber = Watch.GetVariable("CustomerNumber")

dim sqlread

DB_CONNECT_STRING = Watch.GetVariable("global.DB_CONNECT_STRING")

Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

sqlread ="SELECT Count(\*) as NoOfRec ,(\[Customer_Name\])"&\_

" FROM \[TheCat13\]"&\_

" WHERE \[Customer_Number\] = '"&\_

""&CustomerNumber&"'"&\_

"GROUP BY \[Customer_Name\]"

rs.Open sqlread, myConn

if rs.fields("NoOfRec") = 1 then

'Exists

CustomerName = rs.fields("Customer_Name")

else

CustomerName ="Not Found"

end if

rs.Close

watch.setVariable "CustomerName",CustomerName

Watch.Log "Customer Name is "& watch.getVariable ("CustomerName"),3

Error :
\[0014\] W3602 : Error 0 on line 19, column 1: :
\[0014\] W3603 : Error running script.
```

Please advise where went wrong.

Comment: which one is line 19? can you pls format your code?

Comment: Looks like these `&\\` might be a problem. What is the purpose of these backslashes?

Comment: As @GeertBellekens  says, the syntax isn't correct for spanning a string across multiple lines, see the duplicate target for more information.

Comment: Hi all in one script line 19 is : if rs.fields("NoOfRec") = 1 then.