# Group By value to store as a Variable

Tags: group-by, vbscript

i got this query where i require the value retrieve from group by to store as a variable.

My script:

```
sqlread ="SELECT Count(*) as NoOfRec ,([Customer_Name])"&_
  " FROM [TheCat13]"&_
  " WHERE [Customer_Number] = '"&_
  ""&CustomerNumber&"'"&_
  "GROUP BY [Customer_Name]"

rs.Open sqlread, myConn
if NoOfRec = 1 then
        'Exists
        CustomerName = rs.fields("Customer_Name")
else
         CustomerName ="Not Found"
end if
rs.Close
```

Please advise how do i store as variable.

Result to store in a variable

Comment: What is happening with the given code? Errors?

Comment: it does not give the correct value that is found in database it keeps giving "Not Found"

Comment: You are not setting the `Recordset` field `NoOfRec` to the variable `NoOfRec`. Where’s the line `NoOfRec = rs.Fields("NoOfRec")`? This approach is also at risk of SQL Injection vulnerability, would suggest using a parameterised query instead of this.

Comment: Related question [0014 W3602 : Error 0 on line 19, column 1: : will trying to get value from table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78165511/692942)